# Trying to append an element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an element after a user has selected an option from my dropdownlist. Unfortunately I'm not getting the result that I gladly want. The result that I had achieved looked like this:

[image: Faulty result]

As you see the link 'remove' gets incremented after each selected option that has been made by the user. Also there is no space between the created `div` and anchor element. I think I need a for loop to fix the incrementing link `remove`. But I really don't know how. I have tried the following:

```js
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
  var value = $("#theSelect option:selected").val();
  var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

  //theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
  $("#theSelect option:selected").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  var $div = $("<div>", {
    id: "foo",
    class: "a",
    text: value
  });
  //$div.click(function(){ /* ... */ });
  $(".selectContainer").append($div);

  var newLink = $("<a />", {
    id: "id5",
    name: "link",
    href: "#",
    text: "remove"
  });

  $(".a").append(newLink);

});

$("div a.remove").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('rel');
  var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

  $("#theSelect option[value=" + value + "]").removeAttr('disabled');

  $(this).parent().slideUp(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select id="theSelect">
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="Patient">Patient</option>
    <option value="Physician">Physician</option>
    <option value="Nurse">Nurse</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- <div class="hidden isPatient">Patient <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Patient">remove</a></div> -->
<!-- <div class="hidden isPhysician">Physician <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Physician">remove</a></div> -->
<!-- <div class="hidden isNurse">Nurse <a href="#" class="remove" rel="Nurse">remove</a></div> -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important error is that you are appending the remove link to all `div.a` elements

Just append it to the newly created one (*you have a reference to it*)

Instead of

```
$(".a").append(newLink);
```

use

```
$new.append(newLink);
```

---

Additionally, you should cache references to elements you use if you access them more than once. Using native properties is also preferred when available

So this

```
var value = $("#theSelect option:selected").val();
var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

//theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
$("#theSelect option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

can become

```
var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex],
    value = option.value,
    theDiv = $(".is" + value);

option.disabled = true;
```

Last,

- you can bind the remove handler to the element at creation time..
- you also need to set the `rel` attribute
- you need to remove the element instead of just hiding it, since you create new ones each time you change the `select` element
- you need to remove the `id5` since you create multiple links with the same id and that is invalid

All changes together

```
$("#theSelect").change(function(){          
    var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex],
        value = option.value;

    var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

    //theDiv.slideDown().removeClass("hidden");
    option.disabled = true;

    var $div = $("<div>", {id: "foo", class: "a", text: value });
    //$div.click(function(){ /* ... */ });
    $(".selectContainer").append($div);

    var newLink = $("<a />", {
        name : "link",
        href : "#",
        text : "remove",
        rel : value,
        click: remove
    });

    $div.append(newLink);    

});

function remove() { 
    var value = $(this).attr('rel');
    var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

    $("#theSelect option[value=" + value + "]").removeAttr('disabled');

    $(this).parent().slideUp(function() { $(this).remove(); });
};
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pzq8hqjw/7/

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But to be honest I don't understand your first point 'you can bind the remove handler the element at creating time..' Do you mean at the moment I create a div element I also create an anchor element? If so, could you or someone else maybe show how that's done?  Also I had searched on Google about the rel attribute. Is the rel attribute only for a better SEO? Or is there more that I perhaps don't know about it? I do understand your last two points :).

Comment: @superkytoz i forgot the ***to***. "*you can bind the remove handler **to** the element at creation time*. I mean that the way you tried to add the remove handler to the link was not working (*the elements did not exist when your `$("div a.remove").click(..)` code was run*).
So by passing `click: remove` as one of the options to the `var newLink = $("<a />",{..})` code you can set the handler to use when the link is clicked. In my code i have put your remove code in a function and passed it the the link.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".a").append(newLink);
```

appends `newLink` to all the matched tags. Which are in your case, every tag having class `a`(i.e. Nurse, Patient).

But what you want to do is to append `remove` to only the last tag having class `a`.

Then:

```
$(".a:last").append(newLink);
```

will work for you.